# Font Licencing Issue

Tags: font-licensing

My company designed an app for a customer in 2015.  This app was passed to their own developers to code and build.  As this was so long ago any one involved in the project has now left and I can't find any paperwork.  I believe we purchased a web license instead of an app license.  The app was originally living on the clients own website portal (Enterprise Account) and was downloadable by a very niche audience as it is a healthcare app. The app is now also on the Apple Store The app is available in 8 languages. Firstly I would like to know the answers to the following questions:
a) would a web license been sufficient if this app was only ever published on the customers website and not the app store
b) have licensing laws changed for apps at all since 2015
c) Would the app licence cover all 8 countries I would they need a separate license for each country per year it is being used

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You'll need to check the details of the font licence to find out what is or isn't allowed. If the use case scenario is complex, contact the licence provider for clarification. Also legal questions are off-topic here. Try Law Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: Almost certainly the answer is that you need a separate license. Theres no point in naming a web and app licence if they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer. A font license is like a Software Use Agreement, and each creator or foundry can set whichever terms they want when selling a license, there is no general licensing law that establishes the terms for all fonts. So you need to contact the font creator or seller to find out the terms of the license and answer your questions.